# Опустить кнопку

Tags: css3, html5, button

У меня уже есть свёрстанная страничка,только в процессе я видимо что-то не так задала, и получилось, что кнопка расположена прям на тексте, как это исправить?

```css
.content{
 text-align: center;
}

.icon_services,.description,.image_tool{
 display:block;
}

.icon_services{
 padding: 8px 0;
}

.left {
    width: 10%;
    padding: 0 auto;
    float: left;
}

.description{
 vertical-align: top;
 text-align: left;
 float: left;
 width: 60%;
 padding-left: 130px;
}

.description p:nth-child(1){
 font-size:40px;
}

.description p{
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: 400;
}

a:link,a:visited,a:hover,a:active{
 text-decoration:none;
}

.button{
 margin-top: 10px;
 background-color: #fff;
 border:1px solid gray;
 border-radius:20px;
 padding:15px 33px;
 color:#212121;
 font-weight:bold;
}

.services_line{
 height: 5px;
 width: 62px;
 background-color: #ff5c36;
 margin: 18px 0px;
 border-radius: 2px;
}

.image_tool{
 width: 20%;
    float: right;

}
```

```html
<section id="services">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="title_works">
    <h1><span>Services</span> We Provide</h1>
    <div class="titles_first">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis, eveniet.
    </div>
   </div>
    <div class="content">
                <div class="services left">
                    <div class="icon_services"><img src="img/services4.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="icon_services"><img src="img/services2.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="icon_services"><img src="img/services3.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="icon_services"><img src="img/services4.png" alt=""></div>
                </div>
                <div class="description">
        <p>Modern App Design</p>
        <div class="services_line"></div>
        <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime, ullam necessitatibus! Dolor ea iure omnis consequatur voluptate, ut dolorum quisquam. Numquam, voluptatibus id. Odio in dolorem iste aperiam, quam perferendis.</p>
        <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam, voluptatibus id. Odio in dolorem iste aperiam, quam perferendis.</p>
        <a class="button" href="#">+ Know More</a>
      </div>
      <div class="image_tool"><img src="img/watch.png"/></div>
   </div>
 </section>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для кнопки .button установите display: inline-block

Comment: Точно, спасибо!)

Comment: Был вчера похожий вопрос с этим же макетом.